# Searching using more than 1 keywords, on more than 1 fields using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search

I would like to have a search engine using PHP and MySQL to perform searches like this:

I will search for *bumblebee camaro*, in about 3 fields in tables.

I want to have results that return rows with both texts (having *bumblebee* and *camaro*) and also return the same result if I search for *bumblebee cam*.

I was using `MATCH AGAINST IN BOOLEAN MODE`, but the result was record with *bumblebee*, record with *bumblebee and camaro*.

I don't want records with only *bumblebee* text, only the second one. How to do that?

My SQL was: `MATCH (field1,field2,field3) AGAINST('+bumblebee cam' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Thanks for the response in advance!

Btw, I did try to split the keyword, but it was not returning the correct answer, because somehow the word bumblebee from the field1, and camaro from the field2, if i split it. it will show record the one that i dont need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MATCH (field1,field2,field3) AGAINST ('bumblebee cam' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

would search for one of the words

```
MATCH (field1,field2,field3) AGAINST ('+bumblebee +cam' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

would search both words

```
MATCH (field1,field2,field3) AGAINST ('-bumblebee  +cam' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

would search Term without Search

just split the words and build it with using + - | , whatever needed.

check documentation on : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: Btw, I did try to split the keyword, but it was not returning the correct answer, because somehow the word bumblebee from the field1, and camaro from the field2, if i split it. it will show record the one that i dont need